# Is there a way to avoid explicitly writing document fields as Strings in Spring Data MongoDB queries?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have recently started to use Spring Data MongoDB and I wonder if there is any way to avoid writing entities' attributes explicitly as they are stored in the database. For example, given the following class representing a MongoDB collection:

```
public class Employee {

  @Id
  public String id;
  
  private double salary;

  ...
}
```

If I want to make a query using MongoTemplate like:

```
public List findEmployeeBySalaryRange(double salary) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("salary").lt(salary));
        ...
}
```

I would like to avoid writing `"salary"`, since that will make the code harder to maintain in the future in case the field name changes. I am thinking of something like getting the field name from the class attribute, but I am not quite sure how. Is there a way to do it? I have looked into the documentation but did not find anything related unless I missed it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create a Utility Class to store all database field names, use `@Field` annotation on field with constant from that class and use that constant in query to avoid error prone hardcoded Strings.

In Employee Model

```
@Field(DbFields.SALARY)
private double salary;
```

In Query,

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(DbFields.SALARY).lt(salary));
```

In DbFields Utility class

```
public static final String SALARY = "salary";
```

Comment: That would solve the problem. I've upvoted your answer but since I am a new member it is not publicly shown. Many thanks!